# Display Suite - code field retrieve the first value in a multivalue field?

Tags: entities, display-suite

I've created a view mode to display a value multivalue image field. The rendered entity utilizes display suite to display the images. There are 12 images in this field for this all of the nodes of this content type.

Is it possible to just display one image instead of the 12 as a code field in display suite? If so how does one do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra textfield on the manage display screens to limit the output per field where it says # change for a number so you can limit the results. You can also see this video to see how it works [Limit the number of fields to display on Field UI with Display Suite](http://realize.be/limit-number-fields-display-field-ui-display-suite)

There is another video from a drupalcon that I love the way they explain how to render the content in display suite if you need more information.

[take-full-control-your-site-layout-display-suite-drupal-7](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/take-full-control-your-site-layout-display-suite-drupal-7)

Answer (score 3):

When you have a multivalue field, you have also a # on the format column. It represents all images. If you want to show only one or two images, you must write 1 or 2 in the box.

Good luck